# Replace dollar sign with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I try to replace all dollar signs in a string using sed. However, not only the dollar sign gets replaced but the whole string that follows.

`$ echo "abc $def ghi" | sed 's/$//g'`
`$ abc  ghi`

If at least one number is following the dollar sign only the part before the first non-number gets replaced:

`$ echo "abc $123def ghi" | sed 's/$//g'`
`$ abc def ghi`

What is going on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
echo 'abc $def ghi' | sed 's/\$//g'
```

In echo use single quote, if not it means that there is variable def and its substitution and if you don't have variable def it's empty. In sed, you need to escape the dollar sign, because otherwise it means "anchor to the end of the line."

Comment: So basically OP could `def=def` and loose the `sed`. :D

Comment: :D yep. ^_____^

Comment: Oh snap, and I worried so much about my sed syntax. Oh well...:)

Comment: well what if i need double quotes?

Comment: @aimiliano in that case you need to escape $, that's all (otherwise as mentioned above its variable substitution).
 `echo "abc \$def ghi"`

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to remove the character '$' from the string, there is an alternative way using Shell Parameter Expansion. For example:

```
v1='abc $def ghi'
v2='abc $123def ghi'
echo ${v1/$/}
echo ${v2/$/}
```

The syntax is: ${parameter/pattern/string}

If you want to know more about Shell Parameters Expansion look at: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 1):

`tr` should be used for this task, not `sed`.

Use it with single quotes in `echo` to prevent parameter expansion.

`echo 'abc $123def ghi' | tr -d "$"`

Comment: `tr` might be a good tool for this job, but in general it has lots of problems with non-8bit encodings (basically most real-world text)

Comment: So, if you ask directions to go nearest market, I'd be wrong to say that you can go walking straight dozen meters till next block because by walking you can't get to every market in the world?